# Observable - add data with map?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have this code

```
this.store
  .select(s => s.pins)
  .pipe(filter(s => !s.loading))
  .subscribe(pinsState => {
    this.listItems = pinsState.pins;
  });
```

`pins` is an array of objects.

I want to recalculate a value in each object in the array as I get the data. For instance:

```
pins.calculatedval = calcnewval()
```

How do I use the `map` operator to do this? Or is there another operator I should use?

Comment: I noticed you asked serveral questions but never marked any as answered.  If any of the answers solve you problem please remember to mark them as correct with a checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tap()` to alter the pins.  You don't have to return anything, the stream will continue to contain the pinState from `this.store`.

```
this.store
    .pipe(
         filter(s => !s.loading),
         tap(s => s.pins.forEach(pin => pin.calculatedVal = calcnewval()))
     )
     .subscribe(x => this.listItems = x.pins);
```

Also in your original example you use `select()` which I believe is deprecated in favor of `map()` and would cause an error as well since the filter used a property from the parent of the object that you mapped to.

Comment: you can NOT use tap to alter the pipe. you must use MAP as Sachila Ranawaka show

Comment: @Eliseo this will work - try it yourself.  What's passed to the observer to `tap` is the same object that will be used further down the stream.  All I'm doing is changing a property on that object.  In other words, if I wanted to return a different object then I'd have to use `map`, but since I want to keep the original object, I'm fine using tap.

Comment: Daniel, you wrote "you can use tap() to alter the pins". I understood you wanted to say that you change the result of the observable and not. in "this.listItems" you have the original pins.